# Not able to change the color of bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a landing page in bootstrap so i have added the fixed navbar  i want to change the color of navbar (i tried to change the color of navbar by using background-color and !important property but still no any change )how do i solve this problem

here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>MyLandingPage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s.mlcdn.co/animate.css">
<style>
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-default{
  background-color:blue;
  height:60px;
}
#bodycontainer{
  background-image:url(wood.jpg);
  width:100%;
  background-size:cover;
}
form{
  position:relative;
  top:-50px;
}
#myheader h1{
  font-size: 60px;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:250px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;

}
#txt1{
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#txt2{
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#txt3{
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#txt4{
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#txt5{
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
}
.mybutton{
  margin-left:250px;
}
.apple{
  text-align:center;
  width:250px;
}
#txt6{
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
}
#txt7{
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
}
#footer{
  background-color:#B0D1FB;
  width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-brand navbar-header">
        My@PP
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-example">

        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" id="myform">
          <input type="email" placeholder="username@abc.com" class="form-control"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="*********" class="form-control"/>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Log-In</button>
          </form>

      </div>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="container bodycontainer" id="bodycontainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="myheader">
        <h1 class="animated ZoomIn infinite ">MY APPLICATION</h1>
        <p class="lead" id="txt1">This Why You Should Download The App</p>
        <p id="txt2">For more Information about the app please scroll down the more to access the information you can get the idea about it</p>
        <p id="txt3">If u are intrested please join our maling list</p>
        <br/>  <br/>  <br/>
        <form class="">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          </div>
        </form>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg mybutton">Submit</button>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="container bodycontainer">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 id="txt4">Why this app is Osome...?</h1>
      <p id="txt5">Summery of my application</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">

      <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>Header</h2>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius case moderatius no, eu posse phaedrum laboramus nec. Modo eius altera in vel, constituam reformidans at sea. Cu laoreet expetenda iracundia cum, vel an persius feugiat forensibus, at altera similique deterruisset has. Nam doctus viderer
      cu, aliquid prodesset constituam no eum. An nam veritus oportere, qui tritani sanctus et.Et aeterno adversarium mea, mei dicant consul eu. Eum ut sapientem intellegam consectetuer, cum ut stet esse numquam, erant intellegam disputando te mea. Ei quaeque liberavisse nam.
      Ferri nobis suavitate eam at, movet quaestio no has, usu et nibh molestiae posidonium.Usu porro eligendi ea. Ad quo aliquam hendrerit, nam omnis necessitatibus ut. Qui probo propriae delicatissimi et. Id reque aliquam reprehendunt nec, dicunt rationibus at sea, ex vim sint suscipit gloriatur.
     Ea graece partiendo sea.<br/>
     <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Sign-Up</button>


      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">

        <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>Header</h2>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius case moderatius no, eu posse phaedrum laboramus nec. Modo eius altera in vel, constituam reformidans at sea. Cu laoreet expetenda iracundia cum, vel an persius feugiat forensibus, at altera similique deterruisset has. Nam doctus viderer
        cu, aliquid prodesset constituam no eum. An nam veritus oportere, qui tritani sanctus et.Et aeterno adversarium mea, mei dicant consul eu. Eum ut sapientem intellegam consectetuer, cum ut stet esse numquam, erant intellegam disputando te mea. Ei quaeque liberavisse nam.
        Ferri nobis suavitate eam at, movet quaestio no has, usu et nibh molestiae posidonium.Usu porro eligendi ea. Ad quo aliquam hendrerit, nam omnis necessitatibus ut. Qui probo propriae delicatissimi et. Id reque aliquam reprehendunt nec, dicunt rationibus at sea, ex vim sint suscipit gloriatur.
       Ea graece partiendo sea.<br/>
       <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Sign-Up</button>


        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">

          <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>Header</h2>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius case moderatius no, eu posse phaedrum laboramus nec. Modo eius altera in vel, constituam reformidans at sea. Cu laoreet expetenda iracundia cum, vel an persius feugiat forensibus, at altera similique deterruisset has. Nam doctus viderer
          cu, aliquid prodesset constituam no eum. An nam veritus oportere, qui tritani sanctus et.Et aeterno adversarium mea, mei dicant consul eu. Eum ut sapientem intellegam consectetuer, cum ut stet esse numquam, erant intellegam disputando te mea. Ei quaeque liberavisse nam.
          Ferri nobis suavitate eam at, movet quaestio no has, usu et nibh molestiae posidonium.Usu porro eligendi ea. Ad quo aliquam hendrerit, nam omnis necessitatibus ut. Qui probo propriae delicatissimi et. Id reque aliquam reprehendunt nec, dicunt rationibus at sea, ex vim sint suscipit gloriatur.
         Ea graece partiendo sea.<br/>
         <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Sign-Up</button>


          </div>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=" bodycontainer" id="footer">
    <div class="">
      <h1 id="txt6">Download the App</h1>
      <p class="lead" id="txt7">Realy why should i download this?</p>
      <p><center><img src="applelogo.jpg" class="apple"></center></p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script>
$(".bodycontainer").css("min-height",$(window).height());
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is a background image there, who knew?

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color:blue;
  background-image:none;
  height:60px;
}
```

Comment: why to use  background-image:none;

Comment: As I said, the code you are over-riding has background-image (a gradient) specified for that div.

Answer (score 2):

There is predefined background image property in bootstrap theme css

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0,#f8f8f8 100%)
```

This is preventing your background-color to apply.

So, Add `background-image:none;` to `.navbar.navbar-default`.